# How to compare 2nd result to 1st result

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, compare

I've been very frustrated at this problem simply because I don't know how to accomplish this. I am counting points and I want to save the highest score. This is easy, look at my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class POINTS1 : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text countText;
    public Text winText;
    public AudioSource pickUpAudio;
    public AudioSource minus300Audio;

    public int score1;
    public int score2;
    public Text scoreText;

    private int count;


    void Start()
    {

        count = 0;
        SetCountText();
        winText.text = "";
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", count);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", 0);

        PlayerPrefs.GetInt("scorePref");
        score1 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("scorePref");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (scoreText.name == "scoreText")
        {
            scoreText.text = "HS: " + score1;
        }
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("scorePref", score1);

    }


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pickup"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count = count + 100;


            SetCountText();
            {
                pickUpAudio.Play();
            }
        }


        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("minus300"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count = count - 300;



            SetCountText();
            {
                minus300Audio.Play();
            }
        }

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", count);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", 0);




    }

    void SetCountText()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", count);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", 0);
        countText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString();
        if (count >= 5000)
        {
            winText.text = "Good Job!";
        }
            score1 = count;

        if (score1 > count);
        {
            scoreText.text = "HS: " + score1;
        }

        if (score2 > score1);
        {
            scoreText.text = "Score2> 1 " + score1;
        }
    }


    }
```

So, saving the first score is easy. I save the high score using int Score1. However, I don't know how to compare score1 to the new score (score2) the 2nd time someone plays the game. For example, if someone scores 100 the 1st time and 200 the 2nd time, how to I get the game to display a high score of 200? Thank you so much!

Thanks for the effort! I tried to use it but I got many errors I can't seem to fix :( 1: Assets/POINTS1.cs(22,25): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.UI.Text' does not contain a definition for`Text' and no extension method `Text' of type`UnityEngine.UI.Text' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 2:Assets/POINTS1.cs(33,44): error CS1061: Type `int' does not contain a definition for`toString' and no extension method `toString' of type`int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 3: Assets/POINTS1.cs(33,25): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.UI.Text' does not contain a definition for`Text' and no extension method `Text' of type`UnityEngine.UI.Text' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 4: Assets/POINTS1.cs(37,27): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.UI.Text' does not contain a definition for`Text' and no extension method `Text' of type`UnityEngine.UI.Text' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 5:Assets/POINTS1.cs(39,27): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.UI.Text' does not contain a definition for`Text' and no extension method `Text' of type`UnityEngine.UI.Text' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). When I get more time I'll try to fix the errors myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did changes to your code, not able to test them but I think this will help you:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class POINTS1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text winText;
    public AudioSource pickUpAudio;
    public AudioSource minus300Audio;

    public int actualScore;
    public int highScore;
    public Text highscoreText;
    public Text actualScoreText;

    private int count;


    void Start()
    {
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.HasKey("highScore") ? PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highScore") : 0; //This will verify if the key highScore exists in your player prefs, if it exists it should retrieve the stored value if not will return 0;
        actualScoreText.text = "0";
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // if (scoreText.name == "scoreText") //If you are going to set this in the editor, you don't need to verify the name of the object...
        // {
        // scoreText.text = "HS: " + highScore;
        // }

        //Set text for actualScore and highScore (notice that I've created another variable to display the actual score vs the highScore)
        actualScoreText.text = actualScore.ToString() ;
        // We compare the actual score vs the highScore if the actual is greater the we set it to the text variable.
        if (actualScore > highScore)
            highscoreText.text = "HS: " + actualScore;
        else
            highscoreText.text = "HS: " + highScore;
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pickup"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            actualScore += 100;
            {
                pickUpAudio.Play();
            }
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("minus300"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            actualScore -= 300;
            minus300Audio.Play();
//If you want your score not to go below 0, uncomment the next if statement
            //if (actualScore < 0) 
            //{
            //    actualScore = 0;    //With this line your score can't be under 0
            //}
        }

    }

    //I don't know why you called this code many times in the OnTriggerEnter() ....
    // void SetCountText()
    // {
    // PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", count);
    // PlayerPrefs.Save();
    // count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", 0);
    // countText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString();
    // if (count >= 5000)
    // {
    // winText.text = "Good Job!";
    // }
    // score1 = count;

    // if (score1 > count);
    // {
    // scoreText.text = "HS: " + score1;
    // }

    // if (score2 > score1);
    // {
    // scoreText.text = "Score2> 1 " + score1;
    // }
    // }

    void GameOver() //Call GameOver whenever your game is... over, let say .. when your player got N amount of points or N amount of damage...
    {
        if (actualScore >= 5000)
            winText.text = "Good Job";

        if (actualScore >= highScore)
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore", actualScore);
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I tried to use it but I got many errors I can't seem to fix :( Check my edited question.

Comment: try again, I just paste the code into VS and fixed the errors.

Comment: Thank you for the effort! However, the "high score" never changes and in fact doesn't even show on the Canvas, though I've added the text box onto the canvas. So when I get my score of say.. 400, it doesn't save at all :(. Thanks again as most people would give up at this point.

Comment: My bad, it does show on the canvas, and it counts with the actual score. However 2 problems: 1: When I exit the scene and re-enter, it forgets the high score. 2: It won't count negative score :(

Comment: Oops, my bad yet again! Forgot I wasn't using " void GameOver() " yet. Actually it does save the score nicely! Only thing is it won't go into negative score.

Comment: So... you want your score to go under 0? let say.. -300 ? if yes, I have modified the code to do that, also I have added some comments in case you want to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You are never setting score2, and score1 is always equal to count in your code.  I believe these changes will get you what you're looking for.

```
    score2 = count;

    if (score2 > score1);
    {
        score1 = score2;
    }

    scoreText.Text = $"HS: {score1}";

    // EDIT: After doing the comparison, score1 needs to be the HIGH score
```

Comment: So what should I set score1 to? Because I want it to save the highest value of count. Then I want score2 to compare the current count to score1, and display the highest score. This is more of a logic issue than a coding issue :(